How to display tooltips in VS Code for Bootstrap classes?
The functionality that I'm after is being able to see information about a Bootstrap class when hovering the class name in VS Code. Here is an example of equivilent functionality using Tailwind:

I've seen suggestions to use the IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML VS Code extension, but this appears to only provide class name autocompletion.

if there is no extension yet write one with a hover provider and analyze the bootstrap files and display a bit of Markdown when the provider is called and a bootstrap class is under the cursor
